# Laravel replicate including relationships but maintain original timestamps

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to replicate a record and its relationships in Laravel 8. But I want to keep the original records timestamps. I am able to do this on the main record, but the timestamps on all the relationships get set to the datetime that the record is replicated. I also have some observers set up and I dont want them firing when the replication takes place.

```php
$order = App\Models\Order::with('comments', 'tracking_details')->find(4096);


$clone = $order->replicate()->fill([
    'tracking_number' => null,
    'created_at' => $order->created_at,
    'updated_at' => $order->updated_at,
]);

$clone->saveQuietly();


foreach ($order->comments as $comment) {
    App\Models\Comments::withoutEvents(function() use ($clone, $comment) {
        $clone->comments()->create($comment->toArray());
    });
}


foreach ($order->tracking_details as $details) {
    App\Models\TrackingDetails::withoutEvents(function() use ($clone, $details) {
        $clone->tracking_details()->create($details->toArray());
    });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For relationships, you can use query builder instead.

```
// main record

$order = Order::find(4096);

$clone = $order->replicate()->fill([
    'tracking_number' => null,
    'created_at' => $order->created_at,
    'updated_at' => $order->updated_at
]);

$clone->saveQuietly();

// comments relationship

$comments = Comments::toBase()->where('order_id', $order->id)->orderBy('id')->get()->map(function ($item) use ($clone) {
    unset($item->id);

    $item->order_id = $clone->id;

    return (array) $item;
});

Comments::insert($comments->toArray());

// tracking_details relationship

$trackingDetails = TrackingDetails::toBase()->where('order_id', $order->id)->orderBy('id')->get()->map(function ($item) use ($clone) {
    unset($item->id);

    $item->order_id = $clone->id;

    return (array) $item;
});

TrackingDetails::insert($trackingDetails->toArray());
```

In this case you don't work with eloquent, which means that no events will be fired and you will keep the original records timestamps.

Comment: That works perfectly! .. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but have you tried disabling timestamps in your model?

```
public $timestamps = FALSE;
```

Comment: That would disable timestamps through the entire application on that model wouldnt it? ... I just need it for when running the duplicate

Comment: ahh yeah, how about adding the created_at and updated_at fields in its fillables? I think that will do it.

Comment: Is it possible to override them in the toArray method and set them to the original orders value?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your models to be able to save your timestamps via `create()` method, you should add `created_at` and `updated_at` properties to `$fillable` on your models. Reference: [Making properties mass assignable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

The created_at and updated_at columns are default timestamps which Laravel provides out of the box, create a cloned_at column default to null in the database and in your database model, add it to a fillable property, then you can simple insert data in the database where created_at and updated_at values will be parsed as a comma separated value, when retrieving the data, you can split and modify the string from CSV and parse it as a Carbon format, it's a dirty but a possible solution.